# I need to change the name of my data values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data :

[image]

I want to make a loop or something to remove the `(move info)` from my data
for example the first one
`Guyana(more info)` I want it to be just `Guyana` and I want to do that with all the values
thank you so much and have a nice day

Comment: Take a look at [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: please, don't post images of code, errors, output, etc. copy/paste as text.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this, it works for me:

```
df["Country"]=df["Country"].str.replace(' (more info)', '')
```

and here is some extra details on how to use it
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df = df['Country'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","").reset_index()
```

Input:

```
              Country
0  Guyana (more info)
1             Lesotho
2    Iran (more info)
```

Output:

```
   index  Country
0      0   Guyana
1      1  Lesotho
2      2     Iran
```

Answer (score -1):

this should work :

```
df["Country"]=df["Country"].replace(' (more info)', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Looks like you've mixed up your Pandas and your regular Python replace syntax. Regular python doesn't use the third parameter and Pandas operates on a collection rather than a list element. It's a good idea to give a bit more explanation too, posts this short tend to be automatically flagged as low quality and moderators might delete them.